# Object Structure creation where main obejct is a view

Tags: maximo

If main object of an application is a view, then how can we create an object structure for that application?
Which application to be included?

Comment: You want to create a view on top of a view? Why not create a view (new object) based on the base objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create object structures for an object which is view as well.

Say for example, `WOACTIVITY` is the main object in Activities and Tasks application which is a view of `WORKORDER` object. You can create an object structure for `WOACTIVITY` object and you can give activity as the application. However giving the application while creating OS is not mandatory.

I hope I answered your question!